# Django FormWizard on Django default built in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-formwizard, formwizard

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

admin.site.register(Employer,EmployerAdmin) have been used to register this model to admin form. I would like to seperate this form into 2 steps which I fill in the company_name, "Next" to fill in the company_description.

I have been Googling around for few days but things I saw is that all the example used custom html to do this. Can I use the default built-in template used in Django form instead of creating a custom html?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know can help to give me some advice? Appreciate!

Comment: How did you use `admin.site.register(Employer,EmployerAdmin)` to register Company model?

Comment: Sorry, copy the wrong code. It is Employer model.